# Getting data from custom fields in the jos_user table in Joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

```
$user = &JFactory::getUser();

$uid = $user->get('id'); //works 
$umail = $user->get('email'); //works 
$unamed = $user->get('posname'); //does not work
```

Why can't I use JFactory to get the fields that I have added by myself on the Joomla user table. Is there another simple way they could be gotten?

Answer (score 0):

You need the usermeta plugin as posname is not part of the user model

http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/usermeta/

Comment: I tried using it but it does not work. Do I have any other option

Comment: Can you elaborate? What problem are you having?